# Escape Cyrillic, Chinese, Arabic, Hebrew characters in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding

I'm trying to load in a postgres table, records from a flat file, I'm doing it with the Copy command, which has worked well so far.

But now I am receiving fields with words in Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic and other languages, and when I try to do it, it gives me an error in the load.

How could those characters escape in Postgres, I searched, but I have not found any reference to this type of topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape the characters, you should load them as they are.

Your database encoding is UTF8, so that's no problem. If your database encoding is not UTF8, change that.

For each file, figure out what its encoding is and use the `ENCODING` option of `COPY` or the environment variable `PGCLIENTENCODING` so that PostgreSQL knows which encoding the file is in.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe, I did what you suggested and process me without problems